# opengl- does VAO store texrture unit calls as well

Tags: c++, opengl

The very basic foundation for creating a VAO, VBO and applying a texture  goes like this:

```
unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;   //#1
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// position attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// color attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
// texture coord attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);    //#2
```

And for creating a texture:

```
unsigned int texture1, texture2;  
// texture 1
// ---------
glGenTextures(1, &texture1); //#3
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1); //#4
 // set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
// set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
int width, height, nrChannels;
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis.
// The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.
unsigned char *data = stbi_load(FileSystem::getPath("resources/textures/container.jpg").c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);  


//some more code , inside the render loop
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);   #5
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE0, texture1);   #6
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE0, texture1);

glDrawElements(...);
glfwSwapBuffers(...);
//end of render loop
```

According to what I've understood from [`learnopengl`](http://learnopengl.com), from line `#1` to line `#2`, the calls are stored inside the `VAO` which is why we don't have to write the stuff over and over again and we only switch the `VAO` for drawing.
But, is the code from line `#3` to line `#6` also stored in the `VAO`? If it is, then why don't we write line #5 directly after line `#3`? And if it isn't how do we link a specific texture unit to a specific `VAO` if we are using multiple `VAOs`?

EDIT:

after the glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1) the the texture calls that proceed affect the currently bound texture, isn't it? Then does that mean glActiveTexture(...) also affect the currently bound texture?  And why do we bind the texture  again after Activating it using glBindTexture(...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason lines 1 and 2 are "stored inside the VAO" is because that's what those functions do. Those functions set state within the currently bound vertex array object.

A vertex array object, as the name suggests, is an object that deals with vertex arrays. Texture management, texture storage, and using textures for rendering have *nothing* to do with vertex arrays. As such, none of those functions in any way affects VAO state, in much the same way that modifying the contents of a `vector<int>` won't modify the contents of some `list<float>` object.

> how do we link a specific texture unit to a specific VAO if we are using multiple VAOs?

Again, VAOs deal with vertex data. Textures aren't vertex data, so VAOs don't care about them and vice-versa. You don't link textures and VAOs.

You use VAOs and textures (among other things) to perform *rendering*. VAOs and textures each do different things within the process of rendering and thus have no direct relationship to one another.

Comment: after the `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1)` the the texture calls that proceed affect the currently bound texture, isn't it? Then does that mean `glActiveTexture(...)`  also affect the currently bound texture? or is this call independent  of which texture is currently bound? And why do we bind it again after Activating it using `glBindTexture(...)`?

Comment: and is there something like a TO(texture object) that store these texture calls?

Comment: why do we bind the texture again after Activating it using glBindTexture(...)?